# Add "type extensionality" to standard Coq. (part of the univalence axiom)

Tags: coq, homotopy-type-theory

I have a naive question:

> Why don't we add this axiom to Coq:
>
> ```
> Axiom type_extensionality : forall (A B:Type)
>  (f:A->B) (invf:B->A) (H1: forall b, (f (invf b)) = b)
>  (H2: forall a, (invf (f a)) = a), A = B.
> ```

Ok, it'd allow such nonconstructive theorems as (nat->Prop)=(nat->bool) and (A\/B)->(A+B) (the proofs are [here](https://gist.github.com/georgydunaev/4ce30c899d3429314f1de86bcc9873a2)).
But the Coq's standard library already have a lot of nonconstructive axioms.

Will it lead to a contradiction?(If so, where can I read the proof?)
Or it is just not proven yet that axiom will not lead to a contradiction? Maybe it is just useless?

Maybe that is the reason why HoTT library redefines path types in https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/theories/Basics/Overture.v .
This "type_extensionality" axiom is less strong than univalence axiom.
The last will fail with in presence of ProofIrrelevance, PropositionExtensionality. (bool equivalent to itself in two different ways, while bool=bool type consist of only one element).

Comment: How would you prove `nat -> Prop = nat -> bool`?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim The proof of (nat -> Prop) = (nat -> bool) is here: https://gist.github.com/georgydunaev/4ce30c899d3429314f1de86bcc9873a2

Comment: Doesn't the nonconstructivism come from assuming `excluded_middle_informative` rather than this version of univalence? This "type extensionality" implies univalence, so shouldn't we say it's a stronger axiom?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I think that "type extensionality" doesn't imply univalence. If you are really sure about this, then prove me wrong with a Coq code, please.

Comment: Oh I see I was getting hung up on the fact that the assumptions are extensional equivalences, but the real meaningful content of univalence on top of "type extensionality" is that `type_extensionality` as a function is a quasiinverse.